# angularjs select element if false OR null/undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the code below but I would like "No" to be selected if s.x.user_chose_is_formula is false, null, or undefined (all in a single option). How do I do that?

```
            md-input-container.values-type-select
              label Values Type:
              md-select(ng-model="s.x.user_chose_is_formula")
                md-option(ng-value="true") Yes
                md-option(ng-value="false") No
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If (myvar == null) {
}
```

Checks for null or undefined, intentional use of double equals:

```
If (myvar === false) {
}
```

Checks for false, intentional use of triple equals:

```
If (myvar != null && myvar !== false) {
}
```

### Update

You can ignore the older answer above, but it may be helpful to you. In your controller you should initialise your variable so it is either true or false and never null or undefined. If you don't have a controller use `ng-in` it.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. This is from a mongoDB object and by it's nature is most often undefined upon creation

Comment: U can bind to a different variable that is set based on your mongodb var